# Insert some text after a specific div into WordPress frontend

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hook

I am customizing the front end of Woocommerce, so I'd like to add the text "/ Per Month" after my final price before the user clicks the Add to Cart Button.
I have tried through javascript

```js
jQuery('.woocommerce-variation-price').append(" / month")
```

but while it works when I run it from the console it fails when I run it through a file in the template. I can still the code when I check the page code but it does nothing.

I was thinking maybe I could achieve this through a WordPress hook.

I have inserted this in `functions.php`

```
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'permonth_filter' );

function permonth_filter ( $content ) {

    if ( is_single() ) {

        $content .= '<div class="permonth-filter"> / Per Month </div>'     . "
";

    } // End IF Statement

    return $content;

} // End wpcandy_filterhook_signoff()
```

That adds some text at the end of a blog post.
Is there a way to add some text after a specific div with a specific class? `woocommerce-variation-price`

Comment: try to execute js script after page is loaded $(function(){code..});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are running your JavaScript after the page has loaded.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    // Run your code
    $('.woocommerce-variation-price').append(" / month");

}); // end document ready
```